# Area of a region bounded by $y=8$ and $y= |x^2-1|$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, area

What will be the area of the region bounded by $y=8$ and $y=|x^2-1|$?

I am having problem in plotting the graph for area required and the limits for the integral.

Comment: It sounds like your first question is: how to graph $y=|x^2-1|$?

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8588/290189)
I have tried to improve the readability of your question by introducing
[$\rm \LaTeX$](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/). It is
possible that I unintentionally changed the meaning of your question.
Please proofread the question to ensure this has not happened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**

You can divide the region into three parts:

$R_1$ where $x\le-1$ and $x^2-1\ge 0$ and $|x^2-1|=x^2-1$.

$R_2$ where $-1< x< 1$ and $x^2-1<0$, so $|x^2-1|=-(x^2-1)=1-x^2$.

$R_3$ where $x\ge 1$ and $x^2-1\ge 0$, so $|x^2-1|=x^2-1$

The points where both graphs meets are those where $8=|x^2-1|$, i.e.
$$x^2-1=8\qquad \text{or}\qquad x^2-1=-8$$

**New**

It is easy to find the roots: $x=\pm3$.

[image: Graphic]

\begin{align*}
\text{Area}&=\int_{-3}^{-1}\left[8-(x^2-1)\right]dx+\int_{-1}^1\left[8-(1-x^2)\right]dx+\int_1^3\left[8-(x^2-1)\right]dx\\
&=\int_{-3}^{-1}\left(9-x^2\right)dx+\int_{-1}^1\left(x^2+7\right)dx+\int_1^3\left(9-x^2\right)dx\\
&=2\int_0^1\left(x^2+7\right)dx+2\int_1^3\left(9-x^2\right)dx\qquad\text{by symmetry}\\
&=2\left.\left[\frac{x^3}3+7x\right]\right|_0^1+2\left.\left[9x-\frac{x^3}3\right]\right|_1^3\\
&=2\left(\frac13+7-0\right)+2\left[27-9-\left(9-\frac13\right)\right]\\
&=\frac{100}3
\end{align*}

Comment: The answer I'm getting by this method isn't correct. Can you tell me your answer?

Comment: I'm getting 50/3 .

Answer (score 1):

Can you plot $y = x^2 - 1$?

The abolute value will reflect the portion of the plot that would be below the x axis to above the x axis.

Here is a picture.

[image]